# Read Access Database file (.mdb) with NodeJS on Mac?

Tags: node.js, macos, ms-access, meteor

I would like to open a *.mdb file (Access Database) for read only (need a SQL access, not just open the file). 
The main issue is that I need to open it in a NodeJS server, that runs on Mac OS X. 
I want to avoid installing any 3rd-party binaries and/or Microsoft Access Driver on the server - only use a node package or similar.

My server is a Meteor server, so any NodeJS (npm) will be great.

It is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar need and can't seem to find anything. I am developing on a mac and need to query a network .accdb file but cant find a way to do so.